# Reuse of IV for AES CTR stream cipher

Tags: initialisation-vector

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_%28IV%29) describes the following about IV reuse for stream cipher: `For OFB and CTR, reusing an IV completely destroys security. This can be seen because both modes effectively create a bitstream that is XORed with the plaintext, and this bitstream is dependent on the password and IV only. Reusing a bitstream destroys security`. They give a [link](https://cryptosmith.com/2008/05/31/stream-reuse/) for a visual example. My question is that the reuse restriction is per block (i.e. IV different for two blocks) or is the suggestion not to reuse IV for two different plain texts (where plain text is comprised of several blocks) ?

My question specifically relates to AES CTR mode (I am referring to nonce + counter as the IV. So the scenario is that if the attacker can keep IV the same for two blocks. In that case I should make sure IV is different for two blocks ?):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IV (or nonce) must be unique per stream. You can't use a different IV for two blocks in the same stream because there is only one IV.

If part of the keystream repeats, then the XOR of the ciphertext for those blocks will be equal to the XOR of the plaintext. This could happen for instance if the counter value is overflowed, and is why GCM with a 32 bit counter can't be used to encrypt more than 2<sup>32</sup> blocks. Overflowing the counter will increment the nonce, so if the nonce is implemented as an incrementing integer, the keystream will overlap with the next nonce.

Comment: I edited the question. I was trying to ask specifically for CTR mode. I was referring to nonce + counter as the IV. So the scenario is that if the attacker can keep IV the same for two blocks. In that case I should make sure IV is different for two blocks ?

Comment: @Jake How could an attacker keep the IV the same for two blocks? Are you worried about nonces that are close enough that the counter causes them to overlap?

Comment: Yes that's one scenario. I cannot describe my scenario in detail due to NDA, but assume for a moment that it could happen.

Comment: So the conclusion is that IV should be different for every two blocks ? Your edited answer says "xor of two blocks" .. just  to double check if you mean "xor of cipher of 2 blocks" ?